# How do I resolve this React lifecycle interview problem?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was interviewed with the following questions, I got the explained answer by my interviewer. But after the interview, I tried to recreate the problem. I got a different results

Here's the code and the answer is to explain what will be printed in console

```js
function App() {
  const [foo, setFoo] = useState('a');

  useEffect(() => {
    setFoo('b');
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("effect ", foo);
  }, [foo]);

  console.log("render ", foo);

  return (
    <div></div>
    
  );
}
```

The following is my understanding  ( and the interviewer's explanation)

1. it will render the components
2. encountered with `useEffect` and stored them into the stack first
3. 'render a'
4. Have to deal what's inside the stack
5. First useEffect -> knows that we have to setFoo, but wait till other useEffect to be processed
6. Second useEffect -> 'effect a'
7. setFoo('b') and re-render
8. Pass the first useEffect since it's empty dependency
9. put second useEffect into stack
10. 'render b'
11. deal with second useEffect -> 'effect b'

So the output supposed to be

```
'render a'
'effect a' 
'render b' 
'effect b'
```

but when I executed the code, what I got is

```
'render  a'
'effect  a'
'effect  a'
'render  b'
'effect  b'
```

Why is there extra 'effect a'?

And is there any reading material regarding to the lifecycle of functional components?

Comment: Are you using `<StrictMode>`?

Comment: @NicholasTower Yes, I think so, I just use creat-react-app to create a react env for testing, but it's wrapped with `<React.StrictMode>` indeed.

Comment: Then that's the reason the effects are running additional times. [Strict mode](https://reactjs.org/docs/strict-mode.html) deliberately runs things extra times in development builds in order to help highlight bugs from things like not tearing down effects correctly. In a production build, this won't happen.